# Action of a Drinfeld modular group on a Drinfeld symmetric space

Tags: function-fields, modular-group

Let $\Bbb C_\infty$ be functional field case analog of $\Bbb C$, i.e. $\Bbb C_\infty$ is the completion of the algebraic closure of the field of Laurent series $\Bbb F_q((\theta^{-1}))$, where $q$ is a power of prime and $\theta$ is a transcendent element. Let $H\subset M_{(r-n)\times n}(\Bbb C_\infty)$ be the set of Siegel matrices defining $\Bbb F_q[\theta]$-lattices of rank $r$ in $\Bbb C_\infty^n$ - the functional field case analog of an Hermitian symmetric domain. Its closure is $M_{(r-n)\times n}(\Bbb C_\infty)$.

The group $GL_{r}(\Bbb F_q[\theta])$ almost acts on $H$ by the standard formula: if $\gamma \in GL_{r}(\Bbb F_q[\theta])$ has a block structure $\left(\begin{array} A A&B\\C&D \end{array} \right)$ where $A$, $D$ are square matrices of sizes $n$, $r-n$ respectively and $S\in H$ then $\gamma(S)=(C+DS)(A+BS)^{-1}$ (we have almost action, because it is not always defined). The quotient set is the set of $\Bbb F_q[\theta]$-lattices of rank $r$ in $\Bbb C_\infty^n$ up to equivalence.

**Question 1**. Is this quotient set good for all $r$, $n$?

It is well-known that the answer is yes for $n=1$ and $n=r-1$ - this is the Drinfeld upper half space and its dual.

More explicitly, let $r=2n$, and let $\omega\in \Bbb F_{q^2} - \Bbb F_{q}$ be a fixed element; for simplicity we consider the case of odd $q$, and let $\omega^2\in \Bbb F_{q}$. We denote the stabilizer of $\omega I_n$ in $GL_{2n}(\Bbb F_q[\theta])$ by $G_\omega$, it is the set $\left(\begin{array} A A&B\\ \omega^2 B&A \end{array} \right)$ which is isomorphic to $GL_n(\Bbb F_{q^2}[\theta])$.

**Question 2**. Does exist a neighborhood $U$ of $\omega I_n$ in $H$ such that if $S_1$, $S_2\in U$, $\gamma\in GL_{2n}(\Bbb F_q[\theta])$ and $S_2=\gamma(S_1)$ then $\gamma\in G_{\omega}$?

There is a weaker

**Question 3**. Does exist a neighborhood $U$ of $\omega I_n$ in $H$ such that if $S\in U$, $\gamma\in GL_{2n}(\Bbb F_q[\theta])$ and $S=\gamma(\omega I_n)$ then $\gamma\in G_{\omega}$?

We can consider analogs of these questions for the symplectic and orthogonal groups. For example, let $H_s$ be the set of symmetric matrices in $H$. The group $GSp_{2n}(\Bbb F_q[\theta])$ almost acts on $H_s$, an analog of $G_{\omega}$ is denoted by $G_{s\omega}$. It is easy to see that the answer to the analog of Question 3 for the symplectic group is YES (what is a reference?).

What is the answer to the analogs of Questions 1, 2 for the symplectic and orthogonal groups?